# Why can't we prove that union of infinite no of countable sets is also countable by induction?

Tags: real-analysis

If $A1, A2,...., A_m$ are each countable sets then $A1\cup A2\cup.... \cup A_m$ is countable.
Why can't  we use induction to prove that if  $A_n $ is countable for all n then
$\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ is countable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a common mistake.  Induction can be used to show that a statement $P(n)$ is true for infinitely many $n$ (like $n=1, 2, 3, \ldots$), but this does NOT mean that $P(\infty)$ is true (or that it even makes sense).

For a related but more severe example, let $A_n = \{n\}$ for $n=1, 2, 3, \ldots$.  Now prove by induction that $\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i$ is finite.  (This is obviously true without induction, since the union is just $\{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$.)  But by your approach, you would be able to argue that $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i$ is finite, which is really false.

Comment: I don't understand what is $\;P(\infty)\;$ supposed to mean, in particular because ordinary induction (weak or strong) actually means that under this and that assumption, the claim is true **for all** the naturals (or all the naturals beginning with some of them and up).

Comment: It means "naively plug in $\infty$ for $n$ in the statement" which is of course nonsense (and the root of OP's problem).

Comment: (No offense to OP.  It's a common misconception.)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification